# I can't transfer all of my Lamports to another account

Tags: transfer, transfer-checked

If there are 891000 lamports in my account, I can't transfer all of these to another rich account.
It says

> "Transaction simulation failed: Transaction results in an account (0) without insufficient funds for rent".

Answer (score 2):

You can, make sure you transfer the entire exact balance otherwise it will err with "Transaction results in an account (0) without insufficient funds for rent"

```
> solana rent 0 -um
Rent per byte-year: 0.00000348 SOL
Rent per epoch: 0.000002439 SOL
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.00089088 SOL
```

You can check the balance with

```
> solana balance <account> -um
```